# Why is a Powerline adapter working in the lower socket but not in the upper socket?

Tags: powerline-networking, fritzbox

I bought a [FRITZ!Powerline 510E Set](https://en.avm.de/products/fritzpowerline/fritzpowerline-510e-set/) and I installed the two adapters: the first near the switch and the second in the garage.

In the garage I have two blocks of socket:

- One in the lower part near the floor
- One in the upper part near the ceiling.

I need to connect the second Powerline adapter in the upper socket.

The problem is that the Powerline adapters immediately pairs if the second adapter is connected in the lower socket (at about 20 Mbit/sec):

[image]

But they don’t pair if it is connected where it should be in the upper socket:

[image]

I cannot understand why, as the two sockets are connected to the same set of clamps into the electric box:

[image]

Please don't consider the Sonoff device, because its output is connected only to the lower-right socket, not to the sockets where I connected the Powerline adapter.

Could you help me to understand why this is not working as expected?

Comment: What if you rotate the plug 180 degrees? it may work then.

Comment: Have yoou tried using an *extension cord*??

Comment: Trying with last two sockets disconnected the Powerline connects, so I added a single socket with a new dedicated line directly from the clams into the junction box. This way the Powerline connects but it's very unstable and speed is very bad (0,02 Mbit/sec!). Any hints?

Comment: Confused about the close votes on this one.  Isn't Powerline Networking practically by-definition *"personal and home computer networking"*?  Or is there a different reason why it might be off-topic that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably down to increased impedance on the line to your upper socket.

Although anything plugged into that socket receives power quite happily, the high frequency signals used by Powerline are being attenuated.

I would suggest checking and remaking the connections in the back of the socket and in the junction box.  If the connections are clean and tight (which they *should* be anyway) then the Powerline signals stand more chance of getting through.

Comment: I would also get an electrician to verify the two sockets are on the same circuit.

Comment: What do you mean for "circuit"? Yes, both sockets are in the same installation and under the same power meter, as they are connected to the same junction box.

Comment: I added a new single socket with a dedicated line from the junction box and checked and remade all connections in the junction box. Now the Powerline pairs but the speed is ridiculous and very unstable (0,02 Mbit/sec). Do you have any ideas?